# Two dimensional functions convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $T>0$. Let $f:[0, T]\times \mathbb R \rightarrow [0, \infty[$ such that $f\in L^1([0, T]\times \mathbb R)$. I want to prove that there exists a set of full measure $J\subseteq [0, T]$ such that for all $t\in J$,
$$\int_\mathbb R f(t, x)dx \geq C,$$
for a fixed positive constant $C$.

I have proved that for all $g\in C^\infty([0, T]\times \mathbb R)$ and for all $t\in [0, T]$,
$$\int_\mathbb R g(t, x)dx \geq C.$$

Is there any way of approximating $f$ by functions of $C^\infty([0, T]\times \mathbb R)$ in order to prove the statement?

Comment: $f(x,t)$ is almost everywhere zero,then the statement does not hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out $f \equiv 0$ is a counter-example. Even if you avoid this trivial case by assuming that $\int_0^{T}\int_{\mathbb R} f(t,x) dxdt >0$ it is still  false. Take $f(t,x)=t^{2}I_{(0,\frac  1 t)}(x)$ for a counter-example.