# Two dimensional functions: convergence in one dimension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $T>0$. Let $f:[0, T]\times \mathbb R \rightarrow [0, \infty[$ such that $f\in L^1([0, T]\times \mathbb R)$. I want to approximate
$$\int_\mathbb R f(t,x)dx,$$
by integrals of the form
$$\int_\mathbb R g(t,x)dx$$
for $t$-a.e. on $[0, T]$, where $g\in C^\infty([0, T]\times \mathbb R)$.

Is it possible?

Comment: Define $g$ from $f$ with a convolution product with an approximate identity.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. BTW, You are yet to respond to the answer to your previous question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481698/two-dimensional-functions-convergence/3481756#3481756

Comment: I think that you are right in my previous question. I formulated the question in the wrong way, but your answer is still interesting.